# Android MIT App Inventor 2: Merging 4 images into one image file

Tags: android, app-inventor

I have created this screen

[image]

in MIT App Inventor 2, which has 4 canvases in it.
Is it possible to merge the 4 images and output them into 1 image file when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own extension and create a method yourself...

More information about how to create an extension see the [App Inventor Extensions documentation](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/Ip2AX036d0U/5NJlAEbFCgAJ), however that will be more advanced and will require some Java skills...

For some example extensions, see also [my Extensions overview](https://puravidaapps.com/extensions.php)...